# What is the amount of different memories that can be addressed from a 32-bits application running inside a 64-bits os?

Tags: c++, c, memory, operating-system, memory-management

I have a question which might be misinterpreted, so let me explain it with a bit more details.

I know that a 32-bits application running on a 64-bits os will only be able to address at most 4 GB of memory (ram, ...). What I would like to know and was not able to find by myself is (in particular) how much memory I may use from different sources. Or in other words, will I get, for example, 1G from the gpu memory and the remaining from the ram or exactly what I ask until I get to the 4G limit (so 239.83 M from gpu and 3.76 G from cpu) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 gigs comes from the maximum value the a 32-bit word can store.  So, each individual pool could contain 4 gigs.  So yes, 4gigs from the OS, 4gigs from the GPU, 4gigs from the tertiary quantum gigglenator.   64-bit OS or not.

Comment: ...IF they all have completely independent address spaces from the process' perspective.  Often memory from these other sources is mapped into the process' virtual address space, which gives a 4GB limit _total_.

Comment: Nice caveat - you are correct, the addresses must not map to the same area.